# Raspberry pi bootsplash logo modification

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, kernel, framebuffer

I wish to replace the Raspbian kernel boot logos (4 raspberries) with something else. In this case, a single logo of dimensions 320 pixels by 80 pixels that I wish to place in the center of the screen.

So far I've managed to replace the 4 raspberry logos by my single logo. I did this by modifying the kernel code (fbmem.c) to make it think that there is only once cpu available. I've recompiled the kernel to add my new logo and that works ok.

My problem is that I can modify the x location so that the logo sets in the middle of the screen on the horizontal axis, however I cannot displace the logo in the vertical axis. If I displace the logo along the y axis, it starts to disappear, as though it is being clipped somehow - I lose the bottom of my logo. For example, if I set my displacement to 40 pixels, I can only see the top half of my logo.

I do this by adding the following start of the function fb_do_show_logo() in fbmem.c :

image->dx += 800;

image->dy += 40;

Is there any straightforward way of being able place my logo in the middle of the screen? Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found a workaround.

I thought of simply creating a 1920x1080 image and then placing my logo in the middle on a black background. This didn't work, maybe the size of the image is too high in order to be compiled into the kernel.

I tried a logo with a height greater than 80pixels and this seems to work. So to fix the problem, I created an image 320pixels wide by 580 pixels high (1080/2 + 80/2). Then I placed my 80 pixel high by 320 pixel wide logo at the bottom of this image.

I then modified the kernel code (fb_do_show_logo() in fbmem.c) adding image->dx += 800; to displace my 320x580 pixel image in the x axis by 800 pixels and voilà - it works now :)